# Store switcher url is not redirecting to the store

Tags: magento2, url, redirect, magento2.3.3

I'm working on store switcher in magento 2.3.3 I get the url but url is not redirecting to the particular store again get back to the same store

http://test.de/test_de/stores/store/switch/?SID=rl1ktd47ub1hmnmpid1e28e631&___from_store=test_de&___store=mystore_de&uenc=aHR0cDovL3NraXBob3AxMS5kZS9za2lwaG9wX2RlLw%3D%3D

Please anyone help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to Stores -> Configuration and then General -> Web

Make sure Add Store Code to Urls under Url options is set to "Yes"

Flush all cache and reindex the store

Comment: configuration is same but not working